# Can you specify a recipient bitcoin address or an IP address when issuing a transaction

Tags: client, address

when issuing a transaction a bitcoin client could either specify a recipient bitcoin address or an IP address

This statement was in "two bit coins at the price of one" paper, and I am really confused, can I communicate in bitcoins using IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In currently used Bitcoin software (bitcoin-qt 0.8), you cannot specify a recipient IP address, only Bitcoin address.

Sending to an IP address (by contacting specified address and requesting a public key to send to) was possible in past versions, and some form of it might be reinstated in future versions.